# How to add dot separator on different positions of a number in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture a number from a string, which sometimes contains dot separators and sometimes it does not. In any case I need a number with the dot separator.

e.g.:

```
num = re.findall('\d{3}\.(?:\d{2}\.){4}\d{3}|\d{14}', txt)[0]
```

will capture both variations:

```
304.33.44.52.03.002
30433445203002
```

In case it captured the one without dots, I would need to add the dots with the systematic of:

```
AAA.BB.CC.DD.EE.FFF
```

How can I add those dots with Python?

Comment: quick tip for your second question, consider the following bit of code: `'{}{}{}.{}{}.{}{}.{}{}.{}{}.{}{}{}'.format(*list("30.4.33445203002".replace('.','')))`  you can feed this your captures and they will always print in your format regardless of dot separation

Comment: Why don't you do it using regex itself?

Comment: If this is possible with regex, sure would be an option. @Nullman This sounds like a great option. Could you craft an answer from this please?

Answer (score 2):

*Solution without regexp.*

You can transform it to [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) and insert dots in required positions, ensuring that value is [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

```
n = 30433445203002
l = list(str(n))
```

Add dots in positions you need

```
l.insert(3, '.')
l.insert(6, '.')
l.insert(9, '.')
l.insert(12, '.')
l.insert(15, '.')
```

If this is well-defined pattern. You can generalize the insertion above.

After insertion is done, [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them back to the string:

```
num = "".join(l)
```

**Input:**

```
30433445203002
```

**Output:**

```
304.33.44.52.03.002
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture each "group" of numbers into a capturing group, and refer to it in the replacement string. The dots can be made optional with `\.?`.

```
string = "30433445203002"
regex = r"(\d{3})\.?(\d{2})\.?(\d{2})\.?(\d{2})\.?(\d{2})\.?(\d{3})"
pattern = "\\1.\\2.\\3.\\4.\\5.\\6"
result = re.sub(regex, pattern, string)
```

For more details, take a look on [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.sub)

**Output:**

```
304.33.44.52.03.002
```

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CH5c6A/1)

EDIT:

If I have misunderstood you and what you actually want is to *get* the first 3 numbers, 4th and 5th numbers, 6th and 7th numbers etc, you can use the same regex with `search`:

```
re.search(regex, string).group(1) # 304
re.search(regex, string).group(2) # 33
```

Comment: What python do you use? I tried your solution and it seemed pretty interesting but in my interpreter I am getting `"$1.$2.$3.$4.$5.$6"` on your example.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi Edited. I couldn't remember which syntax does python use. It's either `$n` or `\n`. Now it should work.

Comment: your solution looks good and works for me. The only problem with pattern that it matches also other strings. For example, `304.33445203.002` and many more that potentially shouldn't be match. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi My solution only adds the dots. If you want to get the number in each group, you can use the regex with `search` and then call `group`. But if you want to not match anything that is not that pattern, you can use something like `(\d{3})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{3})|(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})`.